# Problem reading a file after create it in c

Tags: c, file, posix

I make a code that create a file, write in it and after read it. But it doesn't read anything and I don't know why. Any suggestion?

```
int main(){
    int fd,n;
    char*c;
    fd=creat("as.txt",0666);
    write(fd,"hola",4);
    lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);
    n=read(fd,&c,4);
    printf("Read: %d \n",n);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: General note: Always check whether your calls succeeded. Right now the `write()` or `seek()` could fail and your code would never know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, write to a buffer with memory allocated to it, not to the *address* of a pointer variable. Also you should account for the null terminator. Furthermore, you should check if the file could be created at all.

Another problem is [`creat(path, mode)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/creat) is equivalent to `open(path, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, mode)`. This means the file is write-only so it is not possible to read from a file descriptor returned by `creat()`. Use `open()` instead, using the `O_RDRW` flag.

```
int main() {
    int fd, n;
    char c[5];
    if ((fd = open("as.txt", O_TRUNC|O_RDRW|O_CREAT, 0666)) == -1) {
        perror("as.txt could not be created");
        return -1;
    }
    write(fd, "hola", 5);
    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
    n = read(fd, c, 5);
    printf("Read: %d \n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! But I have a question if open do the same as creat, in what cases is better to use creat?to write in files? For me it seems like a useless function

Comment: @Michael: the POSIX definition of [`creat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/creat.html)
notes _"The `creat()` function is redundant. Its services are also provided by the [`open()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html)
) function. It has been included primarily for historical purposes since many existing applications depend on it. It is best considered a part of the C binding rather than a function that should be provided in other languages."_. It's so that the old code continues working (and "old" means pre-1990). Don't use it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It should be marked as deprecated to make that clear.